# How to release a file from a process after uploading it to s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a task to migrate some files from disk to amazon s3 bucket.

I upload files using this code and it works as expected:

```
    String bucketName = ...
    String s3HostUrl = ...
    File file = ...

    String s3Key =  generateS3Key(...);
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3Key, file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

`file` referencs a file that have to be uploaded, but after uploading, I have to delete it from disk. The issue is that after uploading, this file cannot be deleted because a process is accessing it.

How can I detach this file from a process and delete the file after uploading to s3?

**Update:**

I just tried defining my own input stream and then closing it, but I have the same situation:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3Key, file)
                .withInputStream(is)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

`s3client.shutdown()` also didn't work.

Comment: Does your attempt to delete the file succeed if you comment out the `putObject()` call?

Comment: @jarmod yes, it does delete the file in that case.